# What is wrong with this ruby for loop?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, control-flow

```
for current_iteration_number in 99..1 do      
   puts "#{current_iteration_number} of beer on the wall. 
   #{current_iteration_number} of beer. Take one down, 
   pass it around #{current_iteration_number} of beer."    
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for current_iteration_number in 99..1 do
```

you can do:

```
for current_iteration_number in 99.downto(1) do
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't work like that for reverse ranges.

You should use some other way of doing it.

For instance:

```
99.downto(1).each do |current_iteration_number|
    puts "#{current_iteration_number} of beer on the wall. #{current_iteration_number} of beer. Take one down, pass it around #{current_iteration_number} of beer."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too

```
a= 99..1

(a.first).downto(a.last).each do |current_iteration_number|
puts "#{current_iteration_number} of beer on the wall. 
   #{current_iteration_number} of beer. Take one down, 
   pass it around #{current_iteration_number} of beer.
end
```